# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.camel.model.config.PropertiesDefinition

Tags: spring, maven, apache-camel

I am developing my first Apache Camel application which is integrated with Spring, but while running the code i am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [apachecamel_spring.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/apache/camel/model/config/PropertiesDefinition;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:414)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:252)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:614)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:515)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.apache.main.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:9)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/apache/camel/model/config/PropertiesDefinition;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.nav.ReflectionNavigator$3.run(ReflectionNavigator.java:288)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.nav.ReflectionNavigator$3.run(ReflectionNavigator.java:285)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.nav.ReflectionNavigator.getDeclaredFields(ReflectionNavigator.java:285)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.nav.ReflectionNavigator.getDeclaredFields(ReflectionNavigator.java:64)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ClassInfoImpl.findFieldProperties(ClassInfoImpl.java:380)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ClassInfoImpl.getProperties(ClassInfoImpl.java:311)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeClassInfoImpl.getProperties(RuntimeClassInfoImpl.java:186)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:261)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:103)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:84)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:227)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:98)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:84)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:375)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:390)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:454)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:292)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:139)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1138)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:162)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:286)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.handler.CamelNamespaceHandler.createJaxbContext(CamelNamespaceHandler.java:188)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.handler.CamelNamespaceHandler.getJaxbContext(CamelNamespaceHandler.java:175)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.handler.CamelNamespaceHandler$CamelContextBeanDefinitionParser.doParse(CamelNamespaceHandler.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.AbstractSingleBeanDefinitionParser.parseInternal(AbstractSingleBeanDefinitionParser.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.parse(AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.java:61)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:74)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1411)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1401)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:172)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:142)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:94)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.camel.model.config.PropertiesDefinition
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 61 more
```

**Below is the main class**:

```
package com.apache.main;

import org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AbstractApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("apachecamel_spring.xml");
        ctx.start();
        System.out.println("Application Context started.......");
        try{
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        ctx.stop();
    }
}
```

**application-camel.xml:** Spring XML file which contains the route

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring
http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">
    <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <route>
            <from uri="file://C:/Users/r2dev/Desktop/Workspace/Folder1?noop=true" />
            <to uri="file://C:/Users/r2dev/Desktop/Workspace/Folder2" />
        </route>
    </camelContext>
</beans>
```

**POM.xml**: I have dependency for camel-core and spring-context.

Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: Which Version of camel-core do you have?

Comment: camel-core : 2.19.1 and spring-core: 4.3.10

Comment: Most likely you have some maven issue.

Answer (score 8):

Looks like the class was moved to an [other package](https://camel.apache.org/maven/camel-2.15.0/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/model/PropertiesDefinition.html) in Version 2.15.0.

Try to use an older version:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.14.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Great this is working now after adding the above dependency. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @RanjuPillai If my answer helps you, feel free to accept it

Comment: I had a similar problem with ClassNotFoundException during the start of an application and it was a good hint here to check the camel dependencies and their versions.